# Gmock - strict mock and unique ptr - how to pass mock to impl

Tags: c++11, googletest, googlemock

Here is an example code:

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual void Start() = 0;
};

class MockInterface: public Interface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Start, void());
};

class T
{
public:
    T(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& impl): impl_(impl){}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Interface>& impl_;
};
```

I would like to create a strict mock but I'm not sure how to construct it as unique ptr and then pass to T constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){};
    virtual void Start() = 0;
};

class MockInterface : public Interface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0( Start, void() );
};

class T
{
public:
    explicit T( std::unique_ptr< Interface > impl ) :
        impl_( std::move( impl ) ) {}
    void Start()
    {
        impl_->Start();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr< Interface > impl_;
};

TEST( Interface_test, Interface )
{
    auto mock{ std::make_unique< MockInterface >() };
    EXPECT_CALL( *mock, Start() );

    auto t{ T{ std::move( mock ) } };

    t.Start();
}
```

Posting a complete answer with an example of usage and an update to the class T.  It is recommended to move the unique_ptr instead of taking a reference.